# Is there a non normal topological vector space?

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

Banach spaces and Hilbert spaces are well-known examples of topological vector space. Is there any topological vector space which is not normal?

Comment: @AnneBauval the discrete topology is incompatible with the vector space structure. It prevents scalar multiplication from being continuous. The cofinite topology has the same problem.

Comment: Do you mean "which is not a normed vector space"? ([Normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space) is something else.) Note that Hilbert spaces are particular cases of Banach spaces. Examples of t.v.s. which are not normed are [locally convex t.v.s.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space).

Comment: To expand on what @AnneBauval has said, are you looking for exotic examples of topological vector spaces or topological vector spaces with a certain property?

Comment: @Anne Bauval I mean normal space not normed vector space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is not normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191646/mathbbr-mathbbr-is-not-normal)